# Find all external relationships in an OOXML/Excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, spreadsheet, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to register all external relationships in a OOXML spreadsheet. The code below provides no results. What am I doing wrong? I suspect I am looking the wrong place, I am looking in "WorkSheetParts". I am using Open XML SDK.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

using (var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(file, false))
{
    var list = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.ToList();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        int count = item.ExternalRelationships.Count(); // Register the number of embedded objects
        if (count == 0) // If no embedded objects, inform user
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"--> {count} external relationships");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"--> {count} external relationships");
            var parts = item.ExternalRelationships.ToList(); // Register each object to a list

            foreach (var part in parts) // Inform user of each object
            {
                Console.WriteLine(part.Uri.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(part.RelationshipType.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(part.IsExternal.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(part.Container.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "no results", what do you mean **exactly**? Does the program simply crash with no output? Does `spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.ToList()` return an empty list?

Comment: Good question.
I think I meant, I have a data sample base, that has embedded objects that is linked, cell links to other spreadsheets and data connections. I would presume any or all of those would lead to being an external relationship.
However the program outputs the count "0" for reach OOXML spreadsheet it iterates.

Comment: Do you have a sample `.xlsx` file we can use to reproduce the issue with? Also, please extract your `.xlsx` file (all OOXML files are just zip files, so you can use 7z, WinRAR, etc) and look at the raw XML files in an editor and ensure that the External Relationship definitions actually exist there and not somewhere else (e.g. User/System DSN?)

Comment: Also, when posting code to the Internet, please be sure to replace all `var` keywords with their **actual** type names, because I have no idea what `var list` or `item.ExternalRelationships.ToList()` actually is... and I'm not going to load your code into VS and fight Office interop just for that.

Comment: Test dataset: https://github.com/Asbjoedt/CLISC/blob/master/Test_Data/Test_Data.zip

I can confirm at least one of the spreadsheets has ext. rel.: 

```<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/externalLinkPath" Target="123.xlsx" TargetMode="External"/></Relationships>```

When I convert var to its types I immediately get error if I change this:
```var list = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.ToList();```

To type WorksheetParts or other.

Comment: What's the error? It shouldn't be anything more than you needing to include `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top.

Comment: I am using that one already. Error is Cannot implicitly convert type 'type' to 'type'

Comment: Also I am not using Office Interop. I am using Open XML SDK.

Comment: Which file are you referring to? I looked inside a few of the OOXML files in `Test_Data.zip` and none of them have any `ExternalRelationship` entries.

Comment: I only see `ExternalRelationship` data in 2 of the files: `Another folder\With chains to cells in another spreadsheet.xlsx` and `Another folder\With embedded objects.xlsx` - is this correct? (i.e. it's _only_ these 2 files, and the others should have zero?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247008/discussion-between-asbjoedt-and-dai).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: You're traversing the OOXML Spreadsheet document structure incorrectly.

The *quick-fix* is to use the built-in `GetAllParts()` extension method, then for each `OpenXmlPart` entry inspect its `ExternalRelationships` property (it's a lazily-evaluated enumerable, *not* an in-memory collection), and looking for  non-empty collections of `ExternalRelationship` objects... or a single linq expression, like so:

```
static List<ExternalRelationship> GetExternalReferences( SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet )
{
    return spreadsheet
        .GetAllParts()
        .SelectMany( p => p.ExternalRelationships )
        .ToList();
}
```

As a more complete example:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

static void Main()
{
    DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo( @"Test_Data" );

    foreach( FileInfo xlsx in root.GetFiles( "*.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories ) )
    {
        SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet;
        try
        {
            spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open( path: xlsx.FullName, isEditable: false );
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "File \"{0}\" cannot be opened: {1}", xlsx.FullName, ex.Message );
            continue;
        }

        using( spreadsheet )
        {
            List<ExternalRelationship> extRels = spreadsheet
                .GetAllParts()
                .SelectMany( p => p.ExternalRelationships )
                .ToList();

            if( extRels.Count > 0 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "File \"{0}\" has {1:N0} external references:", xlsx.FullName, extRels.Count );
                foreach( ExternalRelationship r in extRels )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( "\tUri             : \"{0}\"", r.Uri );
                    Console.WriteLine( "\tRelationshipType: \"{0}\"", r.RelationshipType );
                    Console.WriteLine( "\tIsExternal      : {0}", r.IsExternal );
                    Console.WriteLine( "\tContainer       : {0}", r.Container );
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "File \"{0}\" has no external references.", xlsx.FullName );
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

Output when using files [from the `Test_Data.zip` you posted](https://github.com/Asbjoedt/CLISC/blob/master/Test_Data/Test_Data.zip):

```plaintext
File "Test_Data\Workbook_strict.xlsx" has no external references.
File "Test_Data\Workbook_transitional.xlsx" has no external references.
File "Test_Data\Another folder\123.xlsx" has no external references.
File "Test_Data\Another folder\Created as Strict_Now Transitional.xlsx" has no external references.
File "Test_Data\Another folder\Created as Transitional_Now Strict.xlsx" has no external references.
File "Test_Data\Another folder\Password protected.xlsx" cannot be opened: End of Central Directory record could not be found.
File "Test_Data\Another folder\With chains to cells in another spreadsheet.xlsx" has 1 external references:
    Uri             : "123.xlsx"
    RelationshipType: "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/externalLinkPath"
    IsExternal      : True
    Container       : DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.ExternalWorkbookPart

File "Test_Data\Another folder\With data connection.xlsx" has no external references.
File "Test_Data\Another folder\With embedded objects.xlsx" has 1 external references:
    Uri             : "file:///C:/Users/Sepideh/Desktop/Test_Data/Another%20folder/123.xlsx"
    RelationshipType: "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/oleObject"
    IsExternal      : True
    Container       : DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.ExternalWorkbookPart

File "Test_Data\Another folder\Another folder\1234.xlsx" has no external references.
File "Test_Data\Another folder\Another folder\random1.xlsx" has no external references.
File "Test_Data\Another folder\Another folder 2\New.xlsx" has no external references.
File "Test_Data\Another folder\Another folder\Last folder\some_filename.xlsx" has no external references.
```

Comment: You are an absolute legend. Thank you.